# bash find doesn't find text with underscores in it

Tags: bash, macos, grep, find

new thing making me crazy today:

create a file with this text:

```
get_modal_file_name_from_service
get_modal_file_name_from
get_modal_file_name
get_modal_file
get_modal
```

name it foo.py

then try these commands in order:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs -Ifile grep -nH "get_modal_file_name_from" file
find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs -Ifile grep -nH "get_modal_file_name" file
find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs -Ifile grep -nH "get_modal_file" file
```

but this works:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs -Ifile grep -nH "get_modal" file
```

wtf?  why didn't the first 3 commands work?

Comment: `xargs` is buggy-by-design. Try dealing with filenames with literal backslashes or literal quotes or spaces in their names using it -- unless you're using the `-0` or `-d` extensions, you'll have a bad day. Better to use modern POSIX `find -exec`.

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "bash find". You get the same version of `find` whether you run it from bash, ksh, a Python interpreter, a C program, or anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Problem, In Short

It's nothing to do with the underscores.

Your problem is `-Ifile`, as GNU xargs replaces the sigil specified with `-I` even when it exists as a substring in a larger argument.

#### The Solution, In Detail

Use a sigil that doesn't exist in the name you're searching for -- or better, don't use `xargs -I` at all:

```
# BEST: find ... -exec ... {} +
# (uses modern POSIX find features)
find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec grep -nH "get_modal_file_name_from" '{}' +

# GOOD: find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...
# (just as correct as BEST, but with more startup overhead and not POSIX-compliant)
find . -type f -name "*.py" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nH "get_modal_file_name_from"

# NOT-SO-GOOD: find ... | xargs -I{} ... {}
# (fixes the problem if there's no {} in your search string, but has other bugs)
find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs -I'{}' grep -nH "get_modal_file_name_from" '{}'
```

---

#### The Problem, In Detail

To explain with a concrete example -- let's say you're running this command, and have a file named `./hello.py`:

```
# original, broken command
find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs -Ifile grep -nH "get_modal_file_name_from" file
```

What GNU `xargs` will actually invoke is:

```
grep -nH get_modal_./hello.py_name_from ./hello.py
```

...with the name found substituted not only for the `file` instance passed as its own argument, but also substituted for the `file` in the string `get_modal_file_name_from`.

Comment: ++; for the record, BSD/macOS `xargs` behaves the same with respect to `-I`.

Comment: Ahh. I thought I remembered POSIX explicitly allowing but not mandating this behavior, but went back to the standard and couldn't find an explicit spec either way (admittedly, I also wasn't much inclined to spend an excessive amount of time looking).

Comment: D'oh, yes, that was it.  So obvious now